# How to remove one of two list<object> items based on an object property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I have a list which has items that are similar but have different `createdOn`
dates. I want to only keep the items with same displayName but the latest `createdOn` date. 
I have created a predicate to compare list items based on displayName, so I'm able to find if I have an item with the same displayName, but I'm not sure how do I find the other item with older `createdOn` date and remove it.

> The predicate

```
public bool Equals(Obj x, Obj y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null) { return true; }
            if (x == null || y == null) { return false; }

            return x.DisplayName == y.DisplayName;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Obj obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || obj.DisplayName == null) { return 0; }
            return obj.DisplayName.GetHashCode();
        }
```

> The RemoveDuplicateMethod:

```
public static List<Obj> RemoveDuplicatesSet(List<Obj> items, ValueComparer valueComparer)
    {
        // Use HashSet to maintain table of duplicates encountered.
        var result = new List<Obj>();
        var set = new HashSet<Obj>(valueComparer);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            // If not duplicate, add to result.
            if (!set.Contains(items[i]))
            {
                result.Add(items[i]);
                // Record as a future duplicate.
                set.Add(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Side-Note: you don't need to check if the HashSet contains it, just `Add` it. It will be added if it wasn't contained and returns `true` if it could be added.

Comment: group by identifier, order the group by date descending and take first item for each group

Comment: What is _"The predicate"_? Where is the `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? You also say that you compare by `Id` but you compare by `DisplayName`.

Comment: I'll change it. I meant displayname, i wanted to be discreet. :)

Comment: read about IEqualityComparer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i'd use it in this way:

```
List<Obj> items = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id) // or DisplayName, question is unclear
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First())
    .ToList();
```

You could also pass your comparer to `GroupBy`, although i don't know `ValueComparer`, if it implements `IEqualityComparer<Obj>` it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the data you have but try using LINQ.

```c#
var dItems = items.Distinct();
```

And if you want only lastest ones use lambda expression.

```c#
var dItems = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOn).Distinct();
```

Comment: This might not work since Distinct would take into account the CreatedOn field as well. So, you would end up with duplicate IDs with different CreatedOn Fields.

Comment: You are 100% right. 
Then maybe `var items = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).OrderByDescending(g => g.createdOn).Select(group => group.First());`